# Log-rank test with time-dependent variable

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I am doing survival analysis in R and I want to perform a log-rank test to detect differences between survival curves with a time-dependent covariate.

I use:

```
fit_seasons<- survfit(Surv(time1, time2, status) ~ season,data=dados7)
summary(fit_seasons)
```

to compute the Kaplan-Meier estimated survival.

The `survdiff()` function in the `survival` package does not accept models with time-dependent covariates. And since I am using the counting process, `ictest()` will not work.

What is an alternative way to do this analysis without using the `coxph()` function?

Comment: Why can't you use `coxph()`?